# Would @WebService annotation interfere with @Endpoint in Spring Web Services?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws, enunciate

I'm writing a Spring Boot Web Services application, thus I'm using `@Endpoint` and `@PayloadRoot` annotations.

For documentation purposes I'm using [Enunciate](http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/), which doesn't support Spring-WS annotatinos at the time of writing.

Would it do any harm if I add the `javax.jws.WebService` to an already @Endpoint-annotated class too? Should I use only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have a JAX-WS implementation like CXF in your classpath and configured the WebService annotation will not be considered.